# How can I have this Map double function ignore/skip over empty values?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here it is:

```
Map<double, double> m2 = (await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow: 2))
        .map((key, value) => MapEntry(double.parse(key), double.parse(value)));
    List longitudelist = m2.values.toList();
```

I use that to grab coordinates from a Google sheet. The problem is, when there's no latitude or longitude, the whole thing crashes.

I've tried this under it but it didn't work:

```
latitudelist.removeWhere((isEmpty) => isEmpty == "0.0");
```

The error:

> Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid double

It's an invalid double because there's nothing there. It's not null. Anybody know how to skip over values if latitude or longitude coordinates are not present?

Comment: when you do  `double.parse(value)` on the cell that has no latitude value what does it return? if it 's null or something that can't be parsed to double perhaps you can do something like `MapEntry(double.parse(key), value == null ? null : double.tryparse(value))` and then check for null values

Comment: It returns nothing like so: 
E/flutter ( 6792): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Invalid double
E/flutter ( 6792): 
E/flutter ( 6792): #0      double.parse (dart:core-patch/double_patch.dart:111:28)

trying your suggestion now

Comment: Failed assertion: line 19 pos 16: 'latitude != null': is not true.

Comment: parse and tryparse returns an error if the value is null (or empty in your case, because empty is really null, unless you can see an empty string ''

Comment: 'latitude != null': is not true, where is this latitude value used? can't see it in your code

Comment: It works after I added .removeWhere. Thank you!

Comment: latitudelist.removeWhere((value) => value == null);
    Map<double, double> m2 = (await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow: 2))
        .map((key, value) => MapEntry(double.parse(key), value == null ? null : double.tryParse(value)));
    List longitudelist = m2.values.toList();
    longitudelist.removeWhere((value) => value == null);


This is the working code ^. Thanks again

Comment: I would recommend removing the empty values in m2 before doing map as `(await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow: 2)).removeWhere((k, v) => k == null || v == null).map((key, value) => MapEntry(double.parse(key), double.parse(value)));`, this will clean your map of null values before doing a map and all the subsequent operations wouldn't need to check nullability

Comment: trying this...side question: do you know why this whole thing fails if I don't have values in my first column? it says cannot map 1 to 1 if i move my latitude and longitude to columns 1 and 2... so weird.

Comment: mhmm function expressions removeWhere cannot be named 

    Map<double, double> m2 = (await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow: 2).removeWhere(key, value) 
        => key == null || value == null).map((key, value) => 
        MapEntry(double.parse(key), double.parse(value)));

Comment: yeah forgot it was a void function, add a cascade notation (double dot) before removeWhere..removeWhere(etc)
What do you mean by first column? the google sheet?

Comment: yeah my map function fails entirely if I don't have unique values in my first column. But my code only seems to rely on my 2nd and 3rd columns for lat and lng, and my var markerIdVal is set to equal  UniqueKey();.... i have no idea why i need unique values in column 1 for my plotting function to work. so weird... any idea?

Comment: well I am not sure because I cannot see the google sheet/ plot function or if you use an special packge, but maybe your plot functions require unique values to plot in X/Y axis?

Comment: Map<double, double> m2 = (await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow: 2)..removeWhere(key, value) 
        => key == null || value == null).map((key, value) => MapEntry(double.parse(key), 
        double.parse(value)));  now there are too many positional arguments. one expected but two found.. sorry, this is a little above my head.

Comment: the cascade notation should be used for both removeWhere and map

Comment: hrmm     Map<double, double> m2 = (await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow: 2)
        ..removeWhere(key, value) => key == null || value == null)..map((key, value) 
    => MapEntry(double.parse(key), double.parse(value)));
Map<String, String> cant be assigned to Map<Double, Double>
Converting to Map String String results in too many arguments. Dart is a headache to work with. :/

Comment: Think i figured out why I need a first column value and why it has to be unique. It's the "key." kind of annoying. Going to try to figure out how to do this without a key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do like this

```
List a = [null, null, 4, 6, 7];
a.removeWhere((value) => value == null);
print(a); // prints [4, 6, 7]
```

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work. My value isn't null. It's empty. I get stopped here: MapEntry(double.parse(key), double.parse(value)));

Comment: if key can not be converted to double using `double.parse(key)`  then it will return null.
so you have to handle the null at that time as @EdwynZN suggest.

Comment: @tsy5176 It would be much cleaner to use a `where` before the `toList` in the original conversion than to do a `removeWhere` after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection-for to avoid trying creating `Map` entries from `null` values or empty strings in the first place:

```dart
Map<double, double> m2 = {
  for (var mapEntry in (await sheet.values.map.column(3, fromRow: 2).entries)
    if (mapEntry.key != null && mapEntry.key.isNotEmpty &&
        mapEntry.value != null && mapEntry.value.isNotEmpty)
      double.parse(mapEntry.key): double.parse(mapEntry.value),
};
List<double> longitudelist = m2.values.toList();
```

Comment: a value of type 'Set<MapEntry<double, double>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'Map<double, double>'.

Comment: @tsy5176 Whoops, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `where` before the `toList` method.

```dart
List longitudelist = m2.values.where((v) => v != null).toList();
```

Comment: Probably should mention that this is dependent on using `double.tryParse` instead of `double.parse`.